# Is it possible to track if an email has been clipped?

Tags: email, gmail, html-email, email-analytics

Scenario: Company A sends a daily email to all subscribers which contains a list of real estate properties for rent in that subscribers city.

Each rental property is coded into a simple card format -- title, street address, price, and date listed. For each property, let's say the markup weighs 4kb (after inlining, of course).

The email layout itself is lean, aside from the cards...let's say the file weight is 20kb.

OK. A subscriber in Los Angeles receives his/her daily email. There are seventy-five rental properties in their area, which causes the size of the email to surpass the 102kb limit on Gmail thus clipping that specific subscriber's email halfway through the markup.

But a subscriber living in a small town in Georgia with...let's say 14 properties for rent in their area, would not have their emails clipped.

So, I'm trying to determine if there is a way to track the amount of daily emails to subscribers that are being clipped.

Anyone familiar with a way to detect those metrics? Is there a response from Gmail when an email is clipped that would allow for clipped emails to be tracked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Email tracking is not as it seems in Gmail. Reason being the images are "downloaded" by Gmail and displayed thru their proxy. This means your analytics will show only one activity.

There might be one way to overcome this using Google's email tracking pixel [found here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email). This will enable you to see the stats of email engagement in real time, all the opens.

For clipping, you will need to place the tracking pixel above the fold. I know all providers suggest placing the pixel at the bottom of the email (re: image download time/speed) but if you use Google's tracking pixel I think you can get away with placing the pixel at the very top (after the pre header) since it's just one line of code.

This will mean you can tracking emails using a third method (you platform, litmus and Google).

I hope my answer made sense and was what you were looking for.